# Using AJAX to request SQL Data

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, chart.js

I am using chart.js to create graphs. I'm trying to generate a graph for bdi vs date for specific customers based on their unique IDs. When you visit customer.php that specific customers ID can be found in the URL. I'm trying to request the bdi vs. date data from data.php and query it to generate a line graph.

This is what I have so far:

**Customer.php (Chart.js Code);**

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
            
            url: "charts/data.php",
            method: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   var bdi = [];
   var date = [];

   for(var i in data) {
    date.push( data[i].date);
    bdi.push(data[i].bdi);
   }

   var chartdata = {
    labels: date,
    datasets : [
     {
      label: 'BDI',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(239, 243, 255, 0.75)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(84, 132, 255, 0.75)',
      hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
      hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
      data: bdi
     }
    ]
   };

   var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

   var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: chartdata,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
            
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    fontColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                    fontStyle: "bold",
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 5,
                    padding: 20
                },
                gridLines: {
                    drawTicks: false,
                    drawBorder: false,
                    
                }
}],
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    zeroLineColor: "transparent",
                    display: false
                        },
                ticks: {
                    padding: 20,
                    fontColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                    fontStyle: "bold"
                }
            }]
        },
                    
            tooltips: {
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255)',
                titleFontColor: 'rgb(184,189,201)',
                bodyFontColor: 'black',
                displayColors: false,
                borderColor: 'rgb(214,217,225)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                caretSize: 5,
                cornerRadius: 2,
                xPadding: 10,
                yPadding: 10
            }
        }
});
  },
  error: function(data) {
   console.log(data);
  }
 });
});
```

**data.php:**

```html
<?php
session_start();
//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require_once '../config/config.php';
require_once '../includes/auth_validate.php';


$cid = htmlentities ($_GET['customer_id']);
//get connection

//query to get data from the table
                $sql = sprintf("SELECT treatment_log.bdi, treatment_log.date FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = ? ORDER BY created_at");

                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $cid);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                $data = array();
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $bdi, $date);
                while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                  $data[] = array('bdi' => $bdi, 'date' => $date);
                }
                //free memory associated with result
                $result->close();

                //now print the data
                print json_encode($data);
```

I cant seem to generate a graph. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong!

**Example of data to be graphed:**

```html
[{"bdi":"4","date":"2018-07-11"},{"bdi":"1","date":"2018-07-21"},{"bdi":"5","date":"2018-07-21"},{"bdi":"34","date":"2018-07-21"},{"bdi":"34","date":"2018-07-21"},{"bdi":"3","date":"2018-07-22"},{"bdi":"2","date":"2018-07-23"},{"bdi":"12","date":"2018-07-23"},{"bdi":"3","date":"2018-07-24"},{"bdi":"2","date":"2018-07-25"},{"bdi":"12","date":"2018-07-30"},{"bdi":"3","date":"2018-07-30"},{"bdi":"4","date":"2018-07-30"},{"bdi":"11","date":"2018-07-30"}]
```

Comment: First step is to check the object you are getting back from the server. Is it correct? If so you don't need to include the server code here, but maybe a sample of the data you are attempting to use. Next add a console.log after you generate your date and bdi object. Do you have data to create the chart from? If not maybe you need to parse your data object. Also check console for any errors your chart lib might be throwing.

Comment: I just added a sample of the data Im trying to graph.

Comment: I'm still stuck, I'm not sure how to check the objects im getting back from the server

Comment: The chart lib is 100% fine, i've been able to graph with static Id before

Comment: hit f12 and look at the output in the console tab. That is where your `console.log(data)` will show up. Though in case it's empty i would do `console.log('server output', data)`. Then after your loop through your object to create the date and bdi object add additional console.logs to inspect those objects. You can also google "js breakpoints" or "js chrome debugging" for additional debugging skills.

Comment: I checked before and after I added 'server output', I don't have any data in the console log. Do you have any suggestions, I've been stuck on this issue for a very long time :(

Comment: Looking at your ajax call and your server call you never pass anything to the server. so `$cid = htmlentities ($_GET['customer_id']);` is null/undefined. If you expect it in your php you need to pass it from the client side

Comment: You can use simple print statements to a file on the php side to debug stuff like this. You should print out everything you are getting from the client side and everything you get from the sql call to ensure you have all the values you need.

Comment: I have $cid = htmlentities ($_GET['customer_id']); has bee defined in cutomer.php previously. I just put it in data.php for no reason. Removing it makes no difference .

Comment: How will I be able to check in data.php if i'm getting the ID from customer.php. Doing somthing like echo "customer_id"; doesn't work because in data.php treatment_fk is a variable. So there are a few errors

Comment: Print to file or use logging. If you search how to debug php files you should find an acceptable method